# Update classifier in weka with one instance

Tags: java, classification, weka, updates

I ve trained a Smo classifier in weka and I am interested in update my classifier. I ve found UpdateableClassifier Interface. However, I can't found, how this interface works. How is it then, possible to update my trained classifier with only one instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only those classifiers implementing the [UpdateableClassifier](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/UpdateableClassifier.html) allow that option. Unfortunately, [SMO](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/SMO.html) does not implement this interface, so you have to re-train your classifier on the dataset plus the new instance. Check the page for the interface to see which classifiers currently implement it.